# Как работает дополнительная информация в поисковой выдаче?

Tags: html, seo, поисковые-системы, словари

Рассмотрим сразу на примере: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда подобная информация берётся? Где-то читал, что с помощью различных словарей (data vocabulary, schema.org) можно определить вот такие вещи. **Если да**, то у меня почему-то это не вышло (выложу в обновлении поста, если ответ положительный на самом деле).

Answer (score 2):

Если ориентироваться только на часть вашего скриншота, то, похоже, использовались "[Хлебные крошки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)"

Для Google самым актуальным способом формирования хлебных крошек является использование микроразметки (семантическая микроразметка), Яндекс же автоматически создает хлебные крошки, опираясь, кажется, на используемую сайтом иерархию, структуру.

Очень, кстати, недурной прием - добавлять в микроразметку номер телефона для вывода в СЕРПе. Сам сниппет формируется из Description, а если гугл посчитает его нерелевантным, то возьмет любой кусок из текста на странице. А тут практически беспроигрышный вариант. Номер телефона в любом случае оказывается на глазах пользователя, тем самым выделяя сайт из общей массы наличием контакта.

Вот хороший материал по микроразметке с примерами http://kostyakhmelev.ru/texnicheskaya-chast/mikrorazmetka-schema-org-vnedryaem-na-sait.html#mikrorazmetka-adresa-kontaktnyh-dannyh

Answer (score 1):

Если вы желаете показать номер телефона организации/персоны в поисковой выдаче, то примените разметку структурированными данными для [**Organization**](https://schema.org/Organization) и далее примените элемент **telephone**. Подобное вы можете размечать и для [**Person**](https://schema.org/Person) и далее **telephone**. Для создания вложенности, вы можете применить разметку [**WebPage**](https://schema.org/WebPage) для отдельных страниц или [**WebSite**](https://schema.org/WebSite) для главной страницы и далее через элемент-расширение **mainEntity** переходить к разметке **Организации** или **Персоны**. В этом случая последние разметки будут являться составляющей частью от разметки **Веб Страницы/Веб Сайта**.