# Как сделать такой же сниппет (скрин)?

Tags: html, seo, поисковые-системы, сниппет

Как сделать сниппет, указанный на скрине? Интересует конкретно то, как сделать так же телефон на, само собой, своём сайте?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В сео-разработке не шарю, но есть такое задание - значит нужно делать.
Поэтому просьба объяснять как для чайника, коим я и являюсь =)

Comment: Какой запрос в Google был?

Comment: @edem, ur-adres.kiev.ua

Comment: @Anhk, это название(или alias) одного из разделов сайта, если информация найдена в нём, выводится путь, в данном случае  Звоните ☎(098) 100-17-99 как часть этого пути. Это можете увидеть перейдя на данную страницу снизу

Comment: спасибо, но не понятно, как такие вещи делаются? что использовать? тут явно что-то "дополнительное" же.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого используются так называемые [Microdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)) .

Вся документация есть на сайте https://schema.org/

Вот пример реализации подобного решения

```html
<ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://site.com/">
      <span itemprop="name">Звоните ☎(800) 555-35-35</span>
    </a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

Пример взят [отсюда](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)

Уточню, что `meta itemprop="position" content="1"` указывает на то, в каком порядке выводить "хлебные крошки" при выборке.

Т.е. `content="1">content="2">content="3">content="n"`

На этом же сайте вы можете найти множество полезной информации.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы желаете показать номер телефона организации/персоны в поисковой выдаче, то примените разметку структурированными данными для [**Organization**](https://schema.org/Organization) и далее примените элемент **telephone**. Подобное вы можете размечать и для [**Person**](https://schema.org/Person) и далее **telephone**. Для создания вложенности, вы можете применить разметку [**WebPage**](https://schema.org/WebPage) для отдельных страниц или [**WebSite**](https://schema.org/WebSite) для главной страницы и далее через элемент-расширение **mainEntity** переходить к разметке **Организации** или **Персоны**. В этом случая последние разметки будут являться составляющей частью от разметки **Веб Страницы/Веб Сайта**. Дополнительно смотрите [*мой ответ*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524938/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5) на аналогичный вопрос.